# XSD - not generating all members of enum

Tags: .net, xml, xsd, xsd.exe

I have this in the xsd:

```
<xs:simpleType name="WCODocumentNameCode">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="IM"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="EX"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="CRI"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="CRE"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="CONV"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="RES"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Running XSD.EXE over this (and other files that reference each other) I get the following code generated:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.42")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:wco:datamodel:WCO:DM:1")]
public enum WCODocumentNameCode {

    /// <remarks/>
    CRE,

    /// <remarks/>
    RES,
}
```

Why did the other members of this string enumeration not get generated? How can I generate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the reason. There were multiple classes called the same names and XSD was just generating the last one.

Comment: Did you figure out how to get the different classes referencing the same enums to generate all the values of the enums and not just the last one referenced?

Comment: No sorry I didn’t. I gave up on generating models and hand coded the xml. Turned out easier to write, understand, debug, modify.